# how does Angular HttpInterceptor get called?

Tags: angular, angular-universal, angular-http-interceptors, angular-transfer-state

I'm trying to understand some code here:

[transfer_http.ts](https://github.com/angular/universal/blob/master/modules/common/src/transfer_http.ts)

I'm trying to understand how it invalidates the cache:

```
// Stop using the cache if there is a mutating call.
    if (req.method !== 'GET' && req.method !== 'HEAD') {
      this.isCacheActive = false;
      this.invalidateCacheEntry(req.url);
    }
```

How do you get a situation when req.method !== 'GET'? I only use GET requests.

Comment: Well, if you're following REST, a POST request is used to create data, PUT/PATCH update, DELETE deletes and so on.

Comment: doesn't seem like the best way of knowing when to refresh something. hm

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure why switching request methods would suddenly be a reason to clear the internal cache.

Comment: I guess that as long as you do GET requests on `/documents/56`, the cached version can be used. But if you modify that document, using a POST request, then you would not want to use the cache after that